# how to change color of panel when checkbox is checked angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, accordion

Hey I have this panel which is consist of name and checkbox
what I want is when the checkbox is checked the background color of each panel should change and should stay there when the checkbox is checked.
I tried everything even ngClass but it changes the color but when I go back and come back to the panel the color is back to the way it is white

How can I do that?

**my parent html**

```
<section class="others">
<div class="sub-header">Others</div>
<p class="text-center">{{testText}}</p>
<app-custom-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
<ngb-panel [disabled]="true" *ngFor="let testPanel of otherTests" id="{{testPanel.Id}}" [title]="testPanel.Name">
  <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
    <div class="action-items">
      <span class="material-icons fav" [class.favorited]="testPanel.Favorite"
            (click)="onFavoriteClick(testPanel)"></span>
      <span class="icon-set"
            [ngClass]="{'same-day-2x': isSameDay(testPanel.Code), 'next-day-2x': isNextDay(testPanel.Code)}"></span>
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          class="custom-control-input"
          [name]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker"
          [ngModel]="panelIds.indexOf(testPanel.Id) > -1"
          (ngModelChange)="onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event, testPanel)"
          [id]="testPanel.Id + '-' + testPanel.Moniker">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-panel>
```

**child component app custom accordion**

```
<div class="card">
<ng-template ngFor let-panel [ngForOf]="panels">
<div role="tab" id="{{panel.id}}-header" [class]="'card-header ' + (panel.type ? 'card-' + panel.type: type ? 'card-' + type : '')"
  [class.active]="isOpen(panel.id)">
  <a href (click)="!!toggle(panel.id)" [attr.tabindex]="(panel.disabled ? '-1' : null)" [attr.aria-expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)"
    [attr.aria-controls]="(isOpen(panel.id) ? panel.id : null)" [attr.aria-disabled]="panel.disabled">{{panel.title}}</a>
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.titleTpl?.templateRef"></ng-template>
  <!-- expansion arrows -->
  <div *ngIf="arrowExpand" (click)="toggle(panel.id)" [attr.aria-expanded]="isOpen(panel.id)">
    <span class="material-icons expand"></span>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="{{panel.id}}" role="tabpanel" [attr.aria-labelledby]="panel.id + '-header'" class="card-block" *ngIf="isOpen(panel.id) && panel.contentTpl">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="panel.contentTpl?.templateRef"></ng-template>
</div>
```

I tried ngClass. for the time being it changes the color but I come back color goes back to default white. 
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: When you reload the component, the colour resets to default - this is the expected behaviour, isn't it? Can you provide some more detail on exactly what you're trying to achieve? Maybe make a stackblitz of your problem, or add your component typescript in, that will help.

Comment: yeah i know but what m trying to say is color should not reset

Comment: making stackblitz is difficult because there are six components and one parent component. i will try

Comment: should i add both ts files for these html?

Comment: Using localStorage might fit your needs, here's a good article on a way to achieve this:

https://medium.com/@tiagovalverde/how-to-save-your-app-state-in-localstorage-with-angular-ce3f49362e31 If a user does a hard reload, you will lose localStorage data, however